# How to use Rails date helper methods outside of Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, date

I am converting some Rails controller code to be generic Ruby code. I came across this:

```
expiration_date = 1.hours.from_now.utc.strftime('%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.000Z')
```

...and realized this is not standard Ruby. I get this error message:

```
undefined method `hours' for 1:Fixnum (NoMethodError)
```

How can I convert this to standard Ruby, or require/include the necessary libraries to make this work?

### Solution:

Require the [ActiveSupport Numeric class extensions](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/activesupport/lib/active_support/core_ext/numeric/time.rb):

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'active_support/core_ext/numeric/time'
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is in `activesupport`

include like this

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'active_support/core_ext/date/conversions'
```

Comment: hmm...does not seem to solve the problem for me. Is this the same for activesupport 3.1.3?

Comment: try just with `active_support`

Comment: tried that already. Then I looked up the code on GitHub and found the methods here: [`active_support/core_ext/numeric/time`](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/activesupport/lib/active_support/core_ext/numeric/time.rb) Switching to that seemed to fix it